# How to make the background of an image transparent with Wand?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I have an image with a white background, and want to convert the white background to transparent. How can I do this with Wand?

The ImageMagick command to do this is:

```
convert ~/Desktop/cat_with_white_gb.png -transparent white ~/Desktop/cat_with_transparent_bg.png
```

I have tried:

```
import urllib2

fg_url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz9y0.jpg'
fg = urllib2.urlopen(fg_url)

with Image(file=fg) as img:
    img.background_color = Color('transparent')
    img.save(filename='test.png')
```

and

```
with Image(file=fg) as fg_img:
    with Color('#FFF') as white:
        fg_img.transparent_color(white, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big thing to remember is that JPEG source images will not have an alpha channel. You can add this by defining `wand.image.Image.alpha_channel`, or just setting the image format to something that does work with transparency.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color

with Image(filename="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz9y0.jpg") as img:
    img.format = 'png'
    with Color('#FDFDFD') as white:
        twenty_percent = int(65535 * 0.2)  # Note: percent must be calculated from Quantum
        img.transparent_color(white, alpha=0.0, fuzz=twenty_percent)
    img.save(filename="/tmp/Mz9y0.png")
```

[image: transparant cat]

*perhaps the fuzz of 20% is to aggressive in this example*

Comment: I used 5% fuzz and got decent results for most of what I put through it. Thanks.